# C# : DBConnection.Open() timeout is too long

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to connect to a server that the user inputs. When the server doesn't exist, I'd like to give a quick feedback to the end-user so he can correct what he's typed.

Is there any way to test if a server exists before trying to connect ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your DBConnection have a ConnectionTimeout property? Try setting this to a small number.

Answer (score 2):

ConnectionTimeout property in DbConnection does not have setter. It waits for 15 seconds. You need to specify the timeout in your connection string. "Connection Timeout" in the connection string is in seconds.

```
string connStr = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;" +
                 "Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=5";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) (SMO) to get a list of SQL Servers.  There is a sample of how to get a list of servers [here](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=45).  The enumeration of the servers can take a while but you could always start it in the background when the application loads so that it is ready when the user needs to select a server.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out, although I don't understand how I could list all available servers without specifying anything.

And I need the solution to work for both Oracle and MsSQL.

Comment: Finding the Oracle servers might be a problem.  The SMO object has a EnumAvailableSqlServers function that will scan the network for all SQL servers.  It takes a few seconds to complete but it's great for building a form where the user can see all the SQL servers that are visible on the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can always ping the server or check if a given port is open] but this won't guarantee you that this server won't get offline just before connecting for real.